# Highchart Axis Update/ chart redraw

Tags: highcharts

In my highchart, at some point, I need to update min, max and tickInterval of a yAxis. 
I tried 3 ways:

1. I tried the following code, but it says "object# has no menthod 'update'"

   ```
   var extremes = chart.yAxis[i].getExtremes();
   chart.yAxis[i].update({
           min: extremes.dataMin * 1.1,
           max: extremes.dataMax * 1.1,
           tickInterval : SomeValue,
       });
   ```
2. Also I tried chart.redraw as well... using the following code

   ```
    chart.yAxis[i].min = extremes.dataMin * 1.1;
    chart.yAxis[i].max = extremes.dataMax * 1.1;
    chart.yAxis[i].tickInterval = SomeValue;
    chart.redraw();
   ```

   This time it does not show any error, but the chart does not refreshed as well.
3. This time,I tried to update the options and then to create a new highchart:

   ```
   options.yAxis[i].min = extremes.dataMin * 1.1;
   options.yAxis[i].max = extremes.dataMax * 1.1;
   options.yAxis[i].tickInterval = SomeValue;
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
   ```

It works this time, but I dont want to create a new highchart, I want to update the old one, because I am using it in one another method too.

Please let me know, how this can work, and also if I create new highchart using the 3rd way, then is there a way to get the latest 'chart' variable in another method?

Thank you

Comment: First method should work. Make sure you have latest, 3.0 Highcharts version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this highcharts API:

```
setExtremes (Number min, Number max, [Boolean redraw], [Mixed animation])
```

Link: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes()

They also have some jsfiddle examples there.

EDIT: to change the tickinterval try following:

```
chart.yAxis[0].options.tickInterval = markInterval;
```

Add this too after the above line:

```
chart.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
```

Comment: ^^ Thanks for instant answer. Yes, I could use setExtremes, but I didnt because, I want to change tickInterval as well. I dont want the highchart to choose tickInterval by its own.

Comment: ^^ still not working. See the button 3 in the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/uKWQ9/2/

Comment: @sur the code is working fine. You are setting the extreme from 0 to 25. Since your first value starts from around 30, its not showing in the graph. Change extreme from 0 to 50

Comment: ^^ Problem is not with values, I am aware that its starting with higher values, its just a dummy example. Problem is with tickInterval, it should be 1 in this example, on button click.

Answer (score 0):

you should use other object to trigger yAxis's update method.

exp:

```
var chart = new Highcharts(config);

var axes = chart.axes; // this is all Axis object
var xAxis = axes[0]; // by array's method get axis object
var yAxis = axes[1];

// now, object is ok, next trigger update method
yAxis.update(<your attribute config>);
```

highcharts versions by: "4.1.9"

Answer (score -1):

You have only one option:

```
$(container).highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        max: 10 //you can set the maximum here
    }
})
```

The maximum value can be defined only once. After that, any other changes have no effect to the chart.

```
chart.xAxis[0].options.max = 12; //this statement has no effect
```

Answer (score -1):

Add below lines before setting `chart.addSeries`

```
chart.options.series = false;
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart.options);
chart.render();
```